# Why I am not able to run react-native application on my android device?

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error when I try to run react-native application on my device.

[image: Error Screen]

Steps I did:

1. react-native init SampleApp
2. cd SampleApp
3. react-native run-android
4. react-native start

PS: On first attempt I did successfully run react-native app. Now I am getting this error. I searched a lot but couldn't find solution yet.

Comment: Your android device should get the JS data from server or you should bundle the js files locally. Do you have your server running? npm start

Comment: I did this but getting same error. @abeikverdi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, running `react-native run-android` will open up another command prompt to start the React Packager.

If the packager is somehow not started properly, you can try the following steps:

1. Run `react-native start` first to start the packager server manually.
2. Run `react-native run-android` which it will detect the packager is running and proceed with deploying the application into the device/emulator.

Answer (score 0):

First, you mus open the react-native local packet server:

`react-native start` or `npm start`.

If there is still a problem, may be:

- The IP address might be wrong.
- Phone cannot access the IP address

**Shake** your devices show Menu(or click your devices Menu), click the last item `dev config` setup your computer ip, like `192.168.*.*:8081`

Comment: My device and computer are on different network. Still I need to do this?

Comment: I am doing this already:
1. react-native init SampleApp
2. cd SampleApp
3. react-native run-android
4. react-native start

Comment: That's where the problem is, you need to be in the same network, just like WiFi

Comment: but on very first attempt I run my react native app successfully, and I was on different network too.

Comment: Different networks are not possible to communicate, so you need to be in the same network, and sometimes you don't need to set up because it's automatically set up.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that another application takes port 8081, which is needed for running Metro Bundler. After doing some research, I found out someone does "react-native start" to start the bundler before running "react-native run-ios/android". Running "react-native run-ios" is successful when I previously started the Bundler. After running "react-native run-android", the app can be viewed. However, after could click R to reload the app, it shows 404.

Make sure your port 8081 is not taken by another app. If so, every time when we type "react-native run-ios/android", the Bundler can be automatically started.

When the app is loaded, the window of Bundler should have a progress bar showing the detail of loading the bundle file under ios/android.

BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (481/481), done.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes other applications are running on the default port 8081, so change the port and run the application.

I was facing the same problem, resolved when used different port -->

For windows

correct way is to go to root directory and follow instructions

run cmd as administrator
and run below command

```
npm start -- --port=8888
```

then open another md as administrator in root dir
and run below command

```
npm run android -- --port=8888
```